# Python class method appends item several times in .ipynb environment

Tags: python

Imagine we have a `Class` of `foo` with a certain structure defined in one cell:

```py
class foo:
  def __init__(self, lst = []):
    self.lst = lst

  def appendlst(self, item):
    self.lst.append(item)

  def display(self):
    for item in self.lst:
      print(item)
```

And in the next cell we have an object initialization with method calls:

```py
dummy = foo()
dummy.appendlst(0)
dummy.appendlst(5)
dummy.display()
```

When I run the cell one time, output is as expected to be:

```
0
5
```

But when I run the cell twice, I expect the object to be reinitialized and to print the previous output once, instead I have:

```
0
5
0
5
```

On the opposite, if I reinitialize in the cell in the following manner:

```py
dummy = foo()
dummy.appendlst(0)
dummy.appendlst(5)

dummy = foo()
dummy.appendlst(0)
dummy.appendlst(5)
dummy.display()
```

Output is as expected to be:

```
0
5
```

Also, changing the `self.lst = lst` to be `self.lst = []`, resolves the first case, however, making class incapable for initializing with anything, except the null list.

What is the source of that strange behavior with list being not null, when running the cell twice?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have used the anti-pattern of [using a mutable default value as an argument](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html).

The fix is

```py
  def __init__(self, lst = None):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []
    self.lst = lst
```

In short, by setting the default value to `[]` you are creating a new list and setting the default value to a reference to that list. So every time you call that init function, instead of creating a new list as you were expecting, instead you are getting a reference to a list that is now shared between all your `foo` objects. (Incidentally by pep8 naming conventions you should have called it `Foo`).

This is compounded by Jupyter's design which encourages bad practices like running cells out of sequence leading to unreproducible program states. i.e. be very careful about running or rerunning any cell in Jupyter without running all the cells in order from the start.